# symfony : myUser class => How to access custom property

Tags: symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

I have enabled sfDoctrineGuardPlugin, so I have change `myUser` class to my class extends `sfGuardSecurityUser`.

I have overrided sfGuardUser schema to add my own relation

```
Personnage:
      local: id
      foreign: user_id
      type: one
      onUpdate: CASCADE
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

When models are generated, if go on BasesfGuardUser.class.php, I can see in PHPDoc comments my relation is created and property Personnage has been added.

```
 * @property Personnage $Personnage
```

But I don't understand when I try to access this property, I can't.

In controller :

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$user->Personnage;
```

In view :

```
echo $sf_user->Personnage
```

And the error :

```
Notice: Undefined property: myUser::$Personnage
```

How can I access to this property ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing up two things: the myUser, aka. the session, and the doctrine user, aka. the user's database record.

In symfony projects, the myUser class represents the current session (a wrapper on top of the $_SESSION superglobal).

You can access the database record in you controller via `$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()`, so your relation will work as `$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->Personnage`.

Also see the part regarding [user sessions](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_user_session) of the Gentle Introduction to symfony book.